# Meaning of the word "result" in output when using 'this' as the global object

Tags: javascript, global-variables, this

When executing the following code on Chrome's console, it works as expected:

```
function printNameWithAdj(adjective) {
    alert(this.name + " is " + adjective);
}

var name = "john";
printNameWithAdj.call(this, "nice");
```

and it prints `"john is nice"`.
But when running it in JSFiddle, it gives `"result is nice"`.

Where does `result` come from, and what is the reason for the difference between the environments/engines?

Comment: show the JSFiddle... but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: The global object (`window`) on [jsfiddle.com](https://jsfiddle.net/x4yt5fm1/) has a property `name` with the content `"result"`

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't know what search terms to look for.

Comment: A related one: Why does the value of `window.name` isn't changed in JSFiddle after assigning it a new value (`john`), and it keeps printing `result`?